# Show parent category if there is no subcategory

Tags: categories

I have this code. But when i enter in subcategory which has no own sub, it disappears.
I want if has no subs return parent's subs.

$category->category_parent and $category->parent aren't returning parent cat id.

```
<div style="margin: 0 0 20px 0;">
      <?php $thisCat = get_categories(array('child_of'=>$_GET['cat']));
      if(empty($thisCat)){
                      $thisCat = get_categories(array('parent'=>$_GET['cat']));
      }
                foreach($thisCat as $cat) { ?>
                <div style="margin: 0 25px 0 0; display: inline-block;">
                <a style="font-size: 10pt; color: #777; font-weight: normal;" href="/?cat=<?php echo $cat->cat_ID; ?>"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a><span style="font-size: 7pt; font-weight: bold; background: #f47a6d; padding: 0 4px 0 4px; color: white; border-radius: 1px; margin: -15px 0 0 -5px; position: absolute; text-align: center;"><?php echo $cat->count; ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php }
      ?></div>
```

Example:

- Main category

  - Sub category 1 (has no sub cats)
  - Sub category 2 (has no sub cats)

When i go to "Sub category 1" and "Sub category 2" url i want to show "Main category's" sub categories ("Sub category 1", "Sub category 2") if "Sub Category 1" and "Sub Category 2" has no its own sub categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved problem. It gives subcategory's parent category ID

```
<?php get_term_by('term_taxonomy_id',get_query_var('cat'),'category'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your question is not that clear, I suggest you to improve your question.

You can try adding array parameter `hide_empty` to false in this case `"0"` so that it shows all the category even the one with no post.

```
$thisCat = get_categories(array('child_of'=>$_GET['cat'], 'hide_empty'=>0));
```

You can also refer the [WordPress get_categories Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've added example

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code:

```
$thisCat = get_categories(array('parent'=> $_GET['cat']));
```

Comment: Please don't just dump code, add some explanation on how this bit of code with solve the issue.